# Accessing prestashop context

Tags: php, prestashop

I am developing a prestashop tool which will act as a helper tool for its users. The problem I'm facing is that this will be a stand-alone web app, residing next to a prestashop installation on a server.

My question is how can I tap into prestashop's context to get the signed in user if at all possible? I was thinking to include a core model from prestashop but I have no idea how that works.

If this was a module I could simply access it by calling

```
$this->context
```

Comment: Why create a stand-alone web app? Extend the PrestaShop with your controllers and models, so you can use all the models and controllers of PS, context included. Include the configuration and core files in your web app could be create a security issues as well as unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include these scripts:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'init.php');
```

setting up the correct path.